# PHP value of nothing?

Tags: php, mysql

If have a piece of code that gets some data from a sql database

```
$comms = $row['comments'] ; 

if ($comms != "") {
  $tooltip = "<b>Notes :</b> $comms </br>  ";  
}
```

What i want to do is display the result ONLY if there is something in the data. I am using the if statement to determine if $comms has any data in it but everything i try ("" " " 0 false) returns true. What is the value of nothing when returned (Although I have not included all the code I assure you that there is a value returned in $comms)

Any help would be great , thanks

Comment: NULL comes to mind, more expensively empty()

Comment: Do you know about the === operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!empty($comms)) {
  $tooltip = "<b>Notes :</b> $comms </br>  ";  
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

If you are likely to get a value from the database that contains only whitespaces (I doubt it, but anyway), you will want to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) that variable first:

```
$comms = trim($comms);
if (!empty($comms)) {
  $tooltip = "<b>Notes :</b> $comms </br>  ";  
}
```

In response to @anthares comment (from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)):

> The following things are considered to
>   be empty:
>
> - "" (an empty string)
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (an empty array)
> - var $var; (a variable declared, but    without a value in a class)

Comment: If the comment is "0" this will be considered as empty, right ? Is this OK?

Comment: I know what the function returns. I mean that the OP probably wants to check if the values is NULL only ... and not "0" or "".

Comment: I'm under the impression that `!empty($a)` is true whenever `$a` would evaluate to true.

Comment: Note that a string containing just whitespace is **not** considered empty

Comment: @symcbean - yep, that's why I threw in the `trim` bit.

Answer (score 3):

```
is_null($foo)
```

A propos:

> A variable is considered to be null
>   if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant *NULL*.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been *unset()*.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the `===` and `!==` operators to check both value *and* type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is_null  ( mixed $var  )` function:

```
if (!is_null($comms)){
  $tooltip = "<b>Notes :</b> $comms </br>  ";  
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `!is_null`?

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
$comms = $row['comments'] ; 

if (!isEmpty($comms)) {
    $tooltip = "<b>Notes :</b> $comms </br>  ";  
}
```

Null-checking may also work (as anthares suggested)

Comment: I've not downvoted you, but look the manual of isEmpty function, that you have used. http://php.net/manual/en/splheap.isempty.php

Comment: Sorry guys, actually meant empty(), not isEmpty()